# Kerberos realm understanding

Tags: security, kerberos, encryption-symmetric

Could someone summarise why realms are necessary in Kerberos and the advantages of the concept.

I'm struggling to isolate everything I know / beginning to understand into some well defined points for revision. My research just uncovers articles with so much depth can barely make sense of it. I understand what they are. I am aware that using them means that data is distributed thus advantageous in the event of a system failure and that it is easier to manage many small realms instead of one huge one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit notion of “realm” allows for scaling and federation of Kerberos systems. Imagine two groups A and B which started using Kerberos independently. Each has a completely separate Kerberos system, or realm: a collection of security principals (users and software services) connected to a common Kerberos authentication service, which allows them to authenticate to one another.

Now, these groups want to work together; suppose B has a web server and it wants to allow authenticated access to members of A. This poses a practical problem: the two Kerberos systems do not interoperate. In order to allow authentication, they either have to join the web server to realm A when it already has an identity in realm B, or every user in A has to join B as well (by obtaining a new principal name in B, with a new password, authenticating multiple times and switching between identities depending on what they want to access). It's a mess.

The solution to this is federation: group B decides to trust A’s identification of its own users, rather than requiring them to register independently with B. This is accomplished by giving to A a key which allows its Kerberos system to directly issue credentials good in B’s realm. This is called a one-way realm trust (B trusting A). The B web server can distinguish between users in the different groups, because the realms appear explicitly in the principal names: user@A vs user@B.

To help with the scaling aspect, Kerberos 5 has automatic support for hierarchical realm trusts. If you have three realms FOO, A.FOO, and B.FOO, FOO trusts A.FOO, and B.FOO trusts FOO, then user@A.FOO can authenticate to a service in B.FOO without the realm administrators having to set up a direct trust between A.FOO and B.FOO: Kerberos will follow the trust relationships up and down automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A realm is just a virtual collection of security principals. SASL uses the same notion. For instance, in Windows a domain is a Kerberos realm. Dependening on your case a big realm would make sense. Linking realms reaquires two-way trusts between them. Means more administration overhead for you.
What actual problem do you have?

Comment: Just trying to grasp why Kerberos needs realms to operate. I am of the opinion that it is just in order to satisfy it's main aims of allowing resources / services to be shared and controlled with a group of trusted clients?

Comment: If you need detailed insight, the MIT Kerberos site links to the official maiiling list of Kerberos.